# how in XState machine to do action send('EVENT_NAME', {to:'something from context'})?

Tags: typescript, state-machine, xstate

I need send event to another spawned state machine that its ID I have as a string in a variable in the context. (it is not parent state machine and not child)

Like

`context.sendTo = 'B_id'`

how to do `send()` with parameter from context?

and how to put `send('MY_EVENT_NAME', {to: <something from context> })` in the `MachineOptions` `actions` section?

```
// this does not work...
const myMachineOptions:Partial<MachineOptions<any,any>> = 
{
  actions:{
     mySend: (context, event)=>send('MY_EVENT_NAME', {to: context.sendTo })
  }
}
```

P.S.

it like in the 
[Pass values when sending events from one machine to another in xState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919831/pass-values-when-sending-events-from-one-machine-to-another-in-xstate)

but what I need to by dynamic is not the message body but the `to:` part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

following the help from the developers of the XState https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate/issues/1110

```
actions {
    actionSendMyEvent: 
             send('MY_EVENT_NAME', { to: context => context.sendTo })
    }
```

Huge thanks to the XState developers and maintainers!!!

Comment: It would nice to understand why your original solution did not work.

Comment: @monzie I believe the original solution does not work because `send` is an "action creator" and does not imperatively send the event. See the documentation on the send action: https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/actions.html#send-action (and specifically the warning in that section). You'll notice that the working examples in the documentation take the form of OP's answer as opposed to in his question where the action is a function that returns the result of the `send` action creator.

Comment: Thanks for the questions and answers here @Boris and @Jon. I'm struggling with this setup in a Vue app. I have an `alert-machine` that's instantiated when I start my app. It's a simple machine that I send user notifications too. When I create machines in other files/components Im not sure the best way of sending events to the alert machine as it's already a running service. Do I import the service into other machines? I tried `send('ALERT', { to: 'alert', alert: 'TEST' })` and I get `Unable to send event to child 'alert' from service`. How does a machine send events to another running service?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it somehow?